Allow anonymous to browse packages
After enabling anonymous access, anonymous users can find packages using the search, but they cannot just browse the available packages directly. When logged in, all the packages are shown without needing to search.
Is it possible to display the whole package list for anonymous users as well?
Screenshot of the packages list (left anonymous, right logged in):


I have read this documentation :
https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-grant-an-anonymous-user-access-to-specific-repositories/artifactory-how-to-grant-an-anonymous-user-access-to-specific-repositories
And with the screenshot you can see that you can give permission to anonymous users only at the repositories you have selected before.

Anonymous users have read permission for everything in User Management -> Permissions.
The security configuration also allows anonymous access.
Anonymous also clearly has access in reality, because anonymous can find packages using the search. Artifactory just doesn't show anonymous a list of available packages.
